# How to show up different widget on by clicking which are placed on the same page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, flutter-widget

I want to refer to a different section of a particular stateful widget class which has many other differnt widgets in it.
After a click on a button, it should slide down and show up a particular widget on the same page.

Expected Output:[image: Explained in the image.]

What I have achieved so far is just the pages but could get the same output with that slide up transition

Here's my code snippet:

```
 Positioned(
                        top: 330,
                        left: 1300,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Card(
                            child: Container(
                              height: 100.h,
                              width: 60.h,
                              child: RotatedBox(
                                quarterTurns: 3,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'CONTACT?',
                                    style: blue,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Extracted widget:

```
class AboutUs extends StatelessWidget {
  const AboutUs({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 600.h,
      width: 1300.w,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 10,
            //left: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: 400.h,
              width: 150.w,
              //color: Colors.green,
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/Rectangle 7.png',
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 30,
            left: 60,
            child: Container(
              height: 300.h,
              width: 300.w,
              //color: Colors.green,
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/rect.png',
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 20,
            left: 600,
            child: Text(
              'ABOUT US',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  fontSize: 30,
                  color: AppColors.getLightYellow()),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 50,
            left: 600,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 550.h,
                width: 450.w,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna',
                    style: contact2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 370,
            left: 500,
            child: Container(
              height: 60.h,
              width: 800.w,
              color: AppColors.getLightBlue(),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 330,
            left: 1300,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Card(
                child: Container(
                  height: 100.h,
                  width: 60.h,
                  child: RotatedBox(
                    quarterTurns: 3,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'HOW?',
                        style: blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this problem by approaching in different ways. The easiest solution would be to create a "state" and include a "visible" widget. When you change the widget you replace the visible widget with the new widget that you want to show.

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget _visibleWidget = Text("Not the visible Widget");

  void _changeWidget() {
    setState(() {
      _visibleWidget = Icon(Icons.group);
    });
  }
  ...
```

https://codepen.io/md-weber/pen/eYzZBZz

Another solution would be the [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) widget. It allowes you to control different "page" widgets that you can show and replace.

Comment: The whole content is in the scrollable widget so the content should be visible all the time but I am trying to add a feature wherein if we click on the button the whole page would slide up a bit or will refer to a particular section where we want it.

I have thought of adding a global key to the widgets but could not implement the same as well.